# HttpSendRequest sometimes very slow on Windows 2016 server, works fine on Windows 2008 server

Tags: c++, windows, wininet

I am working on a C++ program using Visual Studio 2013. My problem is that WinInet function `HttpSendRequest` sometimes very slow on Windows Server 2016 server. The same program has been working on Windows Server 2008 for many years without this issue.

Using callback function, I can see it takes long time (15 seconds) between connected to server`(INTERNET_STATUS_CONNECTED_TO_SERVER)`  and sending request `(INTERNET_STATUS_SENDING_REQUEST)`. Does anyone know why `HttpSendRequest` taking long time in that period?

```
14:04:10 Calling HttpSendRequest
14:04:11 Detecting Proxy
14:04:11 Resolving Name
14:04:11 Name Resolved
14:04:11 Connecting to Server
14:04:11 Connected to Server
```

-- taking long time here - 15 seconds

```
14:04:26 Sending request
14:04:26 Request sent (597 Bytes)
```

......

```
14:04:26 Closing Connection
14:04:26 Connection Closed
14:04:26 Handle Closing
```

Comment: You need to post your code (obviously).

Comment: My issue has been solved by using libcurl.